# How to record Mac screen above 60 fps? (120fps, 144fps, ProMotion)

Tags: macos, screen-capture

Shift + Command + 5 generally works great for recording the screen, but it doesn't even seem to try keeping up with ProMotion or any above-60 FPS display. According to QuickTime Player, the directly saved .mov encoded FPS is 59.86.

I'm trying to precisely scrub through a fast system animation, but I can't find any way to record the screen at that framerate - built-in or with an external app. Of course I could put a high-speed external camera to the screen and just try that, or find an high-tech HDMI capture card (as I use a Mac Mini), but those are kind of awkward solutions for what seems to just be a software lack.

Comment: What's your screen's refresh rate? What's the FPS of the process you're trying to record? What's the process? FPS is not in any way related to refresh rate, they spin completely independently… but recording video of the screen will be at maximum your refresh rate, not FPS.

Comment: @Tetsujin The screen refresh rate is 144 Hz, the "process" is built-in system animations: i.e, the whole screen, not a single window. These clearly (to the eye) animate at the full refresh rate, but QuickTime will only record/encode a 60 FPS video.

Comment: Ah, OK. The trouble with 'system anims' is that the system's fps is adaptive to context. For instance, whilst I'm typing this on here, my fps is about 2 or 3. If I change Space it lifts to 60 very briefly [literally for the duration of the animation], then drops straight back to 2 or 3 again. I can't test for refresh rate above 60, but it wouldn't surprise me if it never went above 60, even on a fast refresh display. It's just not ever really needed, so wastes energy. Humans can't really differentiate above that anyway, other than in peripheral vision [the 'prey' zone.]

Comment: I mean, OK, that's a good assessment of the situation in theory, but in practice it's plainly obvious the difference between system animations on a 144 Hz screen and any 60 Hz screen I've ever used [including this monitor in 60 Hz mode], internal or external :-) It's possible I'm "imagining it" because there may be other factors in the monitor which play a factor (i.e. response time). But it seems a 60 FPS recording of a 60 Hz animation ought to look about as smooth as the original (when played back on the same monitor), and it clearly doesn't, so I'm wondering what's up there.